# Can't transition between scale 0 and 1 with css transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I want to make an image begin scaled all the way down in x in, and then animate all the way up in x when classes are added (via javascript).  The pattern that I am using works well for things like rotate, but I am thinking this is only because rotate goes a full 360 degrees.  I am not sure why this does not work:

**CSS:**

```
.scaleXStart {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    transform:scaleX(.5);
}

.scaleXEnd {
    z-index: 3;
    transform: scaleX(2);
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
a = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
a.className = 'scaleXStart';
a.className = 'scaleXEnd';
```

I would think this would work because it is adding and then remove a class, so the `scaleX`property would be set to 0 and then 1 but this is not working. Thanks for any ideas on why

Comment: Could you post your code in a JSFiddle so we can tweak it? Thanks

Comment: Well it should be `querySelector` instead of `queryselector` and you've got a syntax error on the last line. Try fixing these first. Most likely the culprit is the fact that you're changing `className` synchronously, so as far as the browser is concerned, you're setting it to `'scaleXEnd'` every time. Try wrapping the last line in a `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks, those syntax errors were the just the results of me copying the code to SO.  Your point is that this way the classes are set synchronously? I figured they would instantly be set and classified as changed.

Comment: Ah, just read @univerio's comment 2 minutes after I posted an answer - you should've written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, it never gets a chance to get the start class and it goes straight to the end class. Putting the end class change into a timeout (even zero milliseconds!) will trick it into doing the both class changes:

```
function anim(){
    a = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
    a.className = 'scaleXStart';
    setTimeout(function(){a.className = 'scaleXEnd';}, 0)
}
function anim2(){
    a = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
    a.className = 'scaleXStart';
    a.className = 'scaleXEnd';
}
```

See what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/nzJ8j/

Comment: Yep. This works. Is there a cleaner way, I mean, isn't this considered a hack? Either way this is fairly clean, I guess it just doesn't seem cleaner than adding a callback of some sort.

Comment: Yeah, this is a hackish way, but it has to be done due to the nature you're changing classes (and considering each browser has its own implementation of JS, chances are your original code might work in some browsers!). The only natural approach I can think of right now is to add the start class to the div by default and use JS just to add the end class: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/nzJ8j/1/ (the animation will work only once with this code, of course)