# Closure to set element classes in Javascript with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to animate through CSS properties by adding "start" and "end" classNames through javascript.  I have defined a bunch of these classes in CSS (for instance starting with `opacity: 0` and ending with `opacity: 1`

I am trying to loop through all of the elements, set a start `className` on an element, then an end `className` on the element to trigger the transition.  The problem is if I do that how I normally would, by the time the function finishes there would be no actual `className` change.

Using `setTimeout` with even no delay is one way to get around this, as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069510/cant-transition-between-scale-0-and-1-with-css-transitions) but that method does not work in this instance because of my looping.  I am using a closure.

Here is my JS code:

```
var animation = (function () {
        var a = {};
        a.divIndex = -1;
        a.imgIndex = startHolders.length;
        a.animIndex = -1;
        a.divs = startHolders;
        a.run = function () {
                if (++a.divIndex === a.divs.length) a.divIndex = 0;
                if (++a.animIndex === animations.length) a.animIndex = 0;
                if (++a.imgIndex === imageElements.length) a.imgIndex = 0;
                imageElements[a.imgIndex].className = animations[a.animIndex]['start'];
                setTimeout(function() {
                  imageElements[a.imgIndex].className = animations[a.animIndex]['end'];
                }, 0);
            startHolders[a.divIndex].appendChild(imageElements[a.imgIndex]);
    };
    setInterval(a.run, 1000);
    return a;
})();
```

What I really wanted was to be able to set all those indexes to 0 and use `this` instead of `a` (just some placeholder object) but I couldn't do this with the `setTimeout` because of how it changes the value of `this`. Another problem here is that if I put the `if(++a.index) at the bottom of the code, by the time setTimeout runs the value of`a.index` has changed (I believe)  Does anybody know of a workaround here or just a better way?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to improve the code above and to achieve your goal in the same time. If you could build a small even half functional fiddle (and save my time) I believe I could help you 'cause this way I could write next six hours on this subject ;) Anyhow, using a `closure` is a good approach since in general it's far faster than using `bind()`, `apply()` or `call()`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like access to `this` inside of the function passed to `setTimeout` you can use `bind`.

For example:

```
var obj = {}
obj.divIndex = "do you wanna build a snowman?";
obj.run = function () {
  console.log(this.divIndex);
}
setTimeout(obj.run.bind(obj), 1000);
```

I'm thinking you might want to do something like this?:

```
  var a = {};
  a.divIndex = -1;
  a.imgIndex = startHolders.length;
  a.animIndex = -1;
  a.divs = startHolders;
  a.run = function () {
    if (++this.divIndex === this.divs.length) this.divIndex = 0;
    if (++this.animIndex === animations.length) this.animIndex = 0;
    if (++this.imgIndex === imageElements.length) this.imgIndex = 0;
    imageElements[this.imgIndex].className = animations[this.animIndex]['start'];
    setTimeout(function() {
      imageElements[this.imgIndex].className = animations[this.animIndex]['end'];
    }.bind(this), 0);
    startHolders[this.divIndex].appendChild(imageElements[this.imgIndex]);
};
setInterval(a.run.bind(a), 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, here we go. My question though, in your answer, if we are using that inside a self executing function, now that we are using `bind`, is it still necessary to use the placeholder `a` object?

Comment: probably not. I just wasn't sure about what the enclosing scope looks like.

Comment: is there other js and html that go with that fiddle?

Comment: Yes, but that loop is all that is necessary to see the point, which is if we `a` can be replaced with `this`.

Comment: if its not inside a scope of some sort then using this will refer to the window/global object which is generally not desired.